# How can i resolve this limit without L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$$
How can i resolve it without l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Use LaTeX to show math properly. Also, where is $x$ going? $\pm\infty,\,0,\ldots$?

Comment: x going to 0, sorry i don't know how to use LaTeX.Thank you.

Comment: People are down voting because you have not provided any working or context. Please consider adding your thoughts.

Comment: I tried use L'Hopital's rule for get the result of the limit, it works, but i want to know how resolve it without this rule, that's what i thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [power series](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Power_Series_for_Cosine_and_Sine) for $\sin x$. Then $\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^3)$, where $o(x^3)$ stands for the higher order terms, in particular $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{o(x^3)}{x^3}=0$. Subtracting $x$ on both sides, dividing by $x^3$ and taking the limit we get $-\frac1{3!}$.

Comment: thank you for your help! :)